# Sequelize Belongs-To-Many associations without join table?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize on an existing schema and was wondering how to cope with the following situation:

I have a table for sites (where sites have an ICAO airport identifier):

```js
var Site = sequelize.define('site', {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    icao: {
      type: 'CHARACTER',
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
```

And a table with weather time series (with a composite primary key on ICAO and date) :

```js
var Weather = sequelize.define('weather', {
    icao: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    icon: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
```

I believe this is a Belongs-To-Many associations but without a join table. Is there a way to map this schema with Sequelize Models and Associations?

I have try to use the `site` table as the join table:

```js
Site.belongsToMany(Weather, {through: 'site'});
```

but that does not work since `column site.site_uid does not exist`.

Comment: Actually [specifying both keys](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/#belongstomanytarget-options) seems to do the job:
`Site.belongsToMany(Weather, {through: 'site', foreignKey: 'uid', otherKey: 'icao'});` but there may be better options...